# Is this front derailer snapped and/or bent?

Tags: shimano, derailleur, derailleur-front

[image: http://imgur.com/a/P9fVW]

I'm no expert but looks no where close to how it should be.

I think a bit has snapped off?

Also looks to be no where close to the outside of the biggest gear, (even when in that gear). It should kind of encase the chain?

I'm assuming I'll need a brand new part?

Comment: Looks broken to me.

Comment: yes, there should be a part in front of the chain to be able to shift to lower chainrings

Comment: The cage should go around the chain, on both sides.  that one is missing pieces.

Answer (score 2):

Yes.  That is definitely broken, and appears to be irreparable, you will need to replace that.